# Azure SQL Database - Get allowed maximum data storage capacity using powershell/az cli

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I have a database with the following setup (2vCores and 500GB max size)

[image]

I want to increase the allocated max size from say 500GB to 600GB but, before performing that operation I would like to check if there is enough space left for it.

I can get the existing maximum storage size (500GB) with the property "MaxSizeBytes" from the cmdlet Get-AzSqlDatabase.

```
Get-AzSqlDatabase -ServerName <server-name> -DatabaseName <database-name> -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name>
```

how do I get the allowed maximum storage capacity using the PowerShell for the setup? (for 2vCores it is 1024GB)? Is there any specific metric which from which I can get this information instead of from the portal?

**Update**: 
There is a document which has this information (Max data size (GB)  )
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-single-databases?view=azuresql#gen5-hardware-part-1-3

Comment: Fwiw, this REST endpoint appears to give max storage sizes for elastic pools and managed instances, but not databases… https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/capabilities/list-by-location?view=rest-sql-2021-11-01&tabs=HTTP#maxsizecapability - the equivalent Powershell cmdlet is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqlcapability?view=azps-11.0.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-10.3.0